# Installing Mediatomb or other DLNA Server to play files on Samsung series 5 LED TV

Tags: samsung, dlna

Need help installing a DLNA server so as to play video files through the ethernet port on *Samsung Series 5 LED TV*. Most of the links recommended Mediatomb, but I am unable to edit the config file in *etc/mediatomb*.
It says permission denied as you are not the root user.

I am not particularly interested in Mediatomb, any other DLNA server too would do provided I am able to install it on Ubuntu.

I am already using UPnP on Android mobile and Nokia 'Play to' on Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when something like Mediatomb is asking for root permission to do editing, it's because they want you to make sure that you really want to edit such a file - this is to assist in preventing casual and/or unintended changes.

To edit a file like this, you need to temporarily give yourself root permissions - this is the purpose of the sudo command.  You prepend the command that you are using for editing with the word sudo, and the command runs with root permissions, assuming you know the password.

`sudo nano /etc/mediatomb`

will open the file in an editable mode.  If you want to use a graphical editor, you should us gksu (or gksudo) instead of sudo.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running mediaTomb on a system with a flavor of xwindow installed (KDE, Unity, gnome, etc), you can edit the file with gedit. Adding `sudo` to the begining of the command will grant you the security privileges equivalent of that of a root user.

```
sudo gedit /etc/mediatomb/config.xml
```

If you are running it on a server without interface, use `nano` or `vi` instead. [Follow this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MediaTomb).

I would also recommend you enabling the web interface with the following line:

```
 <ui enabled="yes" show-tooltips="yes">
```

And then, in your browser, access it using the port 49152, for example:

```
127.0.0.1:49152
```

If you are looking for alternatives, I recommend looking into [Serviio](http://serviio.org/), I've used it for a while and I was very satisfied.

Hope it helps.